# Mysql Join query for report

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

In my MySQL database, I've 5 tables

Table: Product

| product_id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PA |
| 2 | PB |
| 3 | PC |
| 4 | PD |
| 3031 | PE |

Table: Product_to_category (Product - This table - OneToMany Relation)

| product_id(primary_key) | category_id(primary_key) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 3031 | 439 |
| 3031 | 683 |

Table: Category

| category_id | parent_id | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 71 | 0 | 71-aa |
| 161 | 71 | 161-aa |
| 439 | 161 | 439-aa |
| 680 | 0 | 680-aa |
| 683 | 680 | 683-aa |

Table: Category_description (Category - This table - OneToOne Relation)

| category_id | category_name |
| --- | --- |
| 71 | AC |
| 161 | Split AC |
| 439 | 1TonAC |
| 680 | Offer |
| 683 | SummerChill |

Table: Category_path

| category_id(primary_key) | path_id(primary_key) | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 439 | 71 | 0 |
| 439 | 161 | 1 |
| 439 | 439 | 2 |
| 683 | 680 | 0 |
| 683 | 683 | 1 |

I would like to get results like

| product_id | product_name | category_id | category_name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3031 | PE | 71,161,439 | Defaut Cagegory / AC, Defaut Cagegory / AC/ Split AC, Defaut Cagegory / AC / Split AC / 1TonAc | 71-aa,161-aa,439-aa |

Note: Here 683 is ignored coz there is more than one category of a product. But my requirement is only the first category. That's why 683 was ignored. If not possible to ignore 683 then it should be allowed like 439
Another thing is I need GROUP_CONCAT(category_name) coz I would like to import my existing eCommerce(Opencart CMD) data to Magento 2. Given result pattern is a sample import file for Magento 2.

category_name should be this pattern

"Default Category string" + seperator (/) + "Level - 0 Category"
seperator Comma(,)

"Default Category string" + seperator (/) + "Level - 0 Category/Level - 1 Category"
seperator Comma(,)

"Default Category string" + seperator (/) + "Level - 0 Category/Level - 1 Category/Level - 2 Category"
seperator Comma(,)

Comment: Why does your expected result include category 61, when it doesn't exist (please double check Everything for typos)? Why does category 683 seem to be ignored, or 'Default Category' seem to magically appear (please Explain your requirements, not just dump a wall of data as an example)? Why do you want multiple results in a single row & column (comma delimited lists are a SQL Anti-Pattern)?

Comment: Sorry, i've updated. Its should be 161

Comment: there is more than one product. But I need only the first one. that's why 683 was ignored.

Comment: SQL datasets are unordered; there is no first Category (not product), do you mean the one with the lowest id per product?

Comment: Yes, Lowest id.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` together with the `LEFT JOIN`. I don't know if this returns the correct output for this is untested code but the logic of the query might help you.

```sql
SELECT a.product_id, product_name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.category_id) AS 'category_id', 
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name), ',', '/') AS 'category_name', 
GROUP_CONCAT(c.slug) AS 'slug' FROM product a 
LEFT JOIN product_to_category b ON a.product_id=b.product_id
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.category_id=b.category_id
LEFT JOIN category_description d ON c.category_id=d.category_id
WHERE product_id=3031;
```

Comment: @ShojibFlamon you mean without `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: yes its works, But my requirement is category_name.
It should be this pattern
<Default Category string ><seperator / ><Level - 0 Category> <seperator comma>

<Default Category string ><seperator / ><Level - 0 Category/Level - 1 Category> <seperator comma>

<Default Category string ><seperator / ><Level - 0 Category/Level - 1 Category/Level - 2 Category> <seperator comma>